# inconsolata not working windows 7

Tags: windows, fonts

I have no idea which of the SE sites to ask this on (there's no windows SE site like there is  on [**linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com);) so I'll try this one.

I tried installing [**inconsolata**](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) to use as my default programming font. The problem is, it looks either messed up or is complete gibberish. I'm using windows 7 Home Premium if that helps.

I've included some screenshots so you can see for yourself. The first is of jsfiddle (which uses inconsolata) and the second is netbeans with the same code as the jsfiddle one:

[image: jsfiddle]

---

[image: netbeans]

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a fix for this problem?

I also just noticed that the font isn't even showing up on windows list of fonts

Comment: Java and Chrome both have terrible font rendering problems on Windows (Java still sucks on Linux without tweaking). Chrome isn't something you can fix, but Netbeans should have some font configuration options.

Comment: @Blender Why am I not able to find any of these problems with inconsolata online then?

Comment: Because it isn't a problem with the font. I use this font for my terminal emulator and for my coding font with no side effects, but I use Linux. Your problem is with the software rendering the font.

Comment: @Blender will updating java work? Also why would Netbeans make it into gibberish?

Comment: I don't use Netbeans and I have no idea how Java works, as I don't use Java, but there is documentation: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering

Comment: Seems like the font is not installed correctly.  Delete any related files you can find, then install it again.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think to suggest is to increase the size of the font and see if it renders a little better that way.

I've used Inconsolata on both Windows 7 and 8 (RP), and it seems to work fine in my experience. I've also used it with my own software, without problems. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening for you.

Comment: from where did you download it?

Comment: Hey sarat, I got it from the creator's website (http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html).

He offers the font in a number of formats: SFD, OTF and PFA.

Comment: Visual Studio seems not identifying OTF :( Let me give a shot once again