# inconsolata and netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-7, fonts, 64-bit

When I installed [inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) everything looked fine, however when I tried viewing it on netbeans it look like this:
[image]

I tried using both the ttf and otf versions and they both looked messed up.

Is this a java issue? Win 7 64 bit issue? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What's the problem with that screenshot? Everything seems normal. (There's probably something obvious I didn't notice, haha)

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob So you think what I have about looks like [**this**](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice this was about fonts :P Um, it looks pretty similar though to me.

Comment: Same here, inconsolata looks horrible in NB 7.1.  Consolas looks just fine, as does Droid Mono Sans dotted that I use normally.  Maybe something related to antialiasing?  Check [the Netbeans FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering#Anti-aliasing_in_NetBeans_7.1) and try the different antialias settings?

Comment: btw look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966049/inconsolata-not-working-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try disabling font antialiasing in NetBeans.

Open up your [netbeans.conf](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf)

As part of the `netbeans_default_options` section add `-J-Dswing.aatext=false -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=off`.

Edit: fvu also provided a helpful link to a relevant section in the [NetBeans font rendering FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering#Anti-aliasing_in_NetBeans_7.1).

Comment: @qwertymk I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and just tried NetBeans 7.2 with Inconsolata at 11pt and 13pt, they both looked okay without having to change any settings. Are you using a different profile? Try using a few different profiles, does the issue occur on all of them?

Comment: @qwertymk NetBeans comes with some font profiles by default. Go to "Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors" and there should be a Profile dropdown box, try the "NetBeans 5.5" or "Earth" profiles and change the font to Inconsolata, do you get the same issue? Does the issue occur when using the very similar "Consolas" font?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play around with NetBeans font rendering settings, take a look at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering

Unfortunately, what this article concludes is that default font rendering settings provide the best possible experience. At least under Windows. I have tried all the possibilities with Inconsolata and defaults provide the the best look indeed.

As a workaround, you can try two things:

- Decrease contrast of your color scheme, i.e. by decreasing lightness of a background and/or increasing lightness of your font. It makes font rendering issues less visible.
- Use NegativeScreen: http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/

You may find your experience improved, but this is up to your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just NetBeans, although it is probably not simply the Inconsolata font's fault either.  There seems to be a problem at the level of the underlying Java system that NetBeans is built on.  I say this because the exact same problem shows up in the IDEs created by Jetbrains -- IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, PyCharm, and possibly others.